# How to replace an entire page in jQTouch with another

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqtouch

I have been trying to replace the contents of a page using jQTouch to no success. My problem is [related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

```
$('div.current').replaceAll(html)
```

When I try to do that, the entire page disappears. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try creating a new div with your new contents, and then transition to that.

using r148 of JQT ...

```
var new_div = '<div id="new_div">Hello</div>';
$('#jqt').append(new_div);
jQT.goTo('#new_div','slide');
```

If you are not using 148 I think you could just append to the body tag.

Or maybe you could just use `$('div.current').html(html)` which would not replace the div itself which you need, just the contents inside.